# AngularJS html5mode with fancybox

Tags: angularjs, fancybox-2

I'm using fancybox with angularjs. Fancybox works fine without html5mode but if I enable html5mode page redirects to root when fancybox is shown.

Comment: Can you produce a fiddle?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't. But I found the problem. When I click <a ng-href="/images/{{path}}"...>, $routeProvider redirects to root because of $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'}); How can I disable routing?

Comment: Do you want to disable routing for whole application or just for fancybox urls?

Comment: Just for fancybox urls.

Comment: Then do not redirect to any other page in your $routeProvider.otherwise({})

Comment: I tried but it redirects to /images/357421742514.jpg

Answer (score 2):

I've solved the problem by preventing routing.

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', 
    function (event, next, current) {
        if (next.indexOf('/images/') > 0) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```